# access @html.partial in custom helper in app-code folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, app-code

I put my `.cshtml` file of my custom helper in App-Code folder and it works fine. I want to use `@Html.Partial("_MyPartialView")` in my custom helper, but I can't access `@Html`.

What should I do?